# Bootstrap Carousel Change a particular color div

Tags: javascript, html, css

i´m a little new here, i was looking for the answer and i didn´t find it.

I'm starting as a web designer/web developer.

I have a carousel of images in bootstrap, and a div at the top of it. This div is a simple title to the page.

i want to change the color title for a particular image when this is "active". 
I tried this (because i saw that the image that is showing change its class name: "carousel-item" to: "carousel-item active") , but doesn't work.

This is my HTML:

```html
<div id="titulo">Game of thrones</div>
        <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item " data-interval="3000">
                    <img src="/img/portrait.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="throne">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item active"  id="dragon" data-interval="3000">
                    <img src="/img/dragon.jpeg" class="d-block w-100" alt="got" data-interval="3000">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item" >
                    <img src="/img/houses.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="houses" data-interval="3000">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item" >
                    <img src="/img/evil.jpeg" class="d-block w-100" alt="badguy" data-interval="3000">    
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleInterval" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleInterval" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>

<script>
       const titulo= document.querySelector("#titulo");
       const dragon=document.querySelector("#dragon");


        if(dragon.classList.contains("active")){
            titulo.style.color = "black";
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your current code isn't working is because the script only runs once when the page is loaded. Bootstrap comes with events that you can attach a function to which means you can check the class each time the carousel moves. [You can read more about carousel events here.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#events)

Using the example in the link you can use the following, without changing your existing code too much:

```js
$('#carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
    const titulo = document.querySelector("#titulo");
    const dragon = document.querySelector("#dragon");

    if (dragon.classList.contains("active")) {
        titulo.style.color = "black";
    }
});
```

Note: the event is `slid` not `slide` since the `active` class isn't applied until the slide transition has completed.

---

What might be better is to read the `relatedTarget` of the event and check if that is the dragon:

```js
$('#carousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (evt) {
    const titulo = document.querySelector("#titulo");

    if (evt.relatedTarget.id === 'dragon') {
        titulo.style.color = "black";
    }
});
```